# Is there any way to send route parameter if not using routerLink?

Tags: angular

I wonder is it possible to send route parameter in this `<app-configuration [definition]="c"></app-configuration>` . I have route /configuration and what I need is /configuration/{id} . I know that is possible if using routerLink, but not sure if I can do this by just calling the component.

So to sum up, when I click on tab I need to get ID and pass it as parameter.

```
<mat-tab-group>
        <mat-tab *ngFor="let c of filteredConfigs" [label]="c.displayName">
            <ng-template matTabContent>
                <app-configuration [definition]="c"></app-configuration>
            </ng-template>
        </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to fetch the query parameters from your route URL within the `app-configuration` right?
The value can be accessed by injecting `ActivatedRoute` through `app-configuration`'s constructor and then you may fetch them through the properties of `ActivatedRoute` object.

Comment: I actually want to pass parameter, so I want to know is it posibble to send parameter if I don't use routerLink... So I want to call <app-configuration></app-configuration>  with parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can add data into a route like this:

```
{ path: "testPath1", component: TestComponent, data: { user : "test" } }
```

then, in your code you retreive it like this:

```
this.user = this.route.snapshot.data.user;
```